# Add a wp editor to custom plugin and save data

Tags: php, wp-editor, customization

I'm creating a custom plugin. One of the fields in the plugin let's the user add data.
If I add a `textarea` the user has no control over the text. So I would like to add a editor.
 I know WordPress offers the `wp_editor();` function.
After some Google-ing I found that it is very easy to implement the editor.:

```
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

This shows a nice editor. The problem is that the content isn't getting saved.

The editor is a part of a form so I thought I add the save function to the form save function like this:
 `if( isset( $_POST[ 'mycustomeditor' ] ) ) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mycustomeditor', array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_POST[ 'mycustomeditor' ]) );}`

However WordPress thinks different about this. It does create the `meta_key` in the database but no value.

I hope anyone can see what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it!

Hope somebody else can use it or it answers their problem. If there is a better way please share and tell why.

```
$editor_id = 'custom_editor_box';
$uploaded_csv = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_editor_box', true);
wp_editor( $uploaded_csv, $editor_id );
```

To save the data:

```
function save_wp_editor_fields(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_editor_box', $_POST['custom_editor_box']);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_wp_editor_fields' );
```

And that's all there is to it!

Comment: You should sanitize this with `wp_kses_post()` before saving it to the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have it in one of my plugins:

```
<?php
wp_nonce_field('nonce_action', 'nonce_field');
$content = get_option('my_content');
wp_editor( $content, 'settings_wpeditor' );
?>

function settings_save_wpeditor(){
// check the nonce, update the option etc...

if(isset($_POST['settings_wpeditor']) && isset($_POST['nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce_field'], 'nonce_action') ){
update_option('my_content', wp_kses_post($_POST['settings_wpeditor']));
}
}

add_action('admin_init', 'settings_save_wpeditor', 10);
```

Be sure to add prefixes to your variables and option names and also look up wp_none and wp_verify_nonce from the WordPress codex.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce

Answer (score 0):

```
$editor_id = 'product_summary';

$summary =  get_post_meta( $post->ID,'product_summary', true );
wp_editor( $summary, $editor_id );
if( isset( $_REQUEST['product_summary'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_summary',wp_kses_post( $_POST['product_summary'] ) );
    }
```

value update in `wp_editor` but not update the value in database, please check and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi that is the solution of your problem, Just copy and paste and see.....

```
    function dhansikhi_hukamnama_post_page(){
    ?>
    <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>My Super Admin Page</h2>
    <form method='post'>
    <?php
    wp_nonce_field('nates_nonce_action', 'nates_nonce_field');
    $content = get_option('special_content');
    wp_editor( $content, 'special_content' );
    submit_button('Save', 'primary');
    ?>
    </form>
    </div><!-- .wrap -->
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dhansikhi_hukamnama_page' );
```

Comment: Problem was all ready solved!